# React Native code editor / IDE with intellisense/code-completion

Tags: react-native, ide, intellisense, code-completion, code-editor

React Native code editor/IDE with intellisense/code-completion?

I have heard of WebStorm but it is not free.  Anyone using one that is free and you would recommend it?

Comment: There are a lot of editors that can be tweaked to provide code completion.
[For example](https://code.visualstudio.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem**

You would like code completion for developing `React Native` applications.

**Solution**

Facebook has a `Atom` plugin called `Nuclide` which comes with code completion. You can install this plugin to a fresh install of Atom and have code completion.

**Steps**

1. Install Atom [from here](https://atom.io/)
2. Open Atom and go to preferences.
3. Click on Packages
4. Type in Nuclide and click install

For more information on setting up Nuclide with Atom take a look at the setup pages [here](https://nuclide.io/docs/editor/setup/).

Comment: I think he meant developing the native and react part with one IDE. Jetbrains IDEA fails at supporting both, it does not recognize android Java project and the documentation tells you to mark it as excluded which is a huge fail, since its a Java IDE.